# How to check if a post is deleted with Graph Api?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'am getting post detailes via Facebook Graph api, process it and store it in the database.
But some post is deleted, and i want thos post delete from the database, or just hide them. Does there any way i can check if a post is deleted. This is the message when i want to open the facebook post

> This post has been removed or could not be loaded.

Comment: The API will return the same error message (“Unsupported GET request …”) for content that does not exist, or that you are simply not allowed to read with the access token used. So whether or not you will be able to do this at least to some degree, will depend on the access token used and permissions granted.

Comment: Okey, but what is the request, because now i am geting posts from facebook groups like /{id}/feed?fields=... and weh i have the post id how should i make a request? That is what i dont know.

Comment: `/post_id` - d’oh?

Comment: Thanks :D 
Now i realized, I already tried this, just always with deleted post, and i tought that i was doing something wrong.